# How to wait until os.system() executes?

Tags: python, os.system, fasttext

I am using `os.system()` to execute the first commend mentioned [here](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/autotune.html). It essentially trains a `fasttext` supervised model with autotune enabled. But important thing is that, the program flow continues to next line before train completes and also before saving the model file. Both the training and model file saving happen with this single command.

So, basically I want to prevent the program to move to the next line until the commend executes, how to achieve it?

Comment: Consider using module `subprocess` instead of `os.system()`

Comment: @BoarGules would you elaborate? Say, the command is a string which is stored in some variable `cmd`.

Comment: You can't easily get `os.system()` to wait until the command finishes.  The `subprocess` module was written to replace it (and other modules) in Python 3.5 (nearly 7 years ago). It is now the standard approach, and it does what you want. `subprocess.run()` will wait for the command to complete. That is why I suggested that `os.system()` was not the way to go.